# Modify keys and values of a dict in a list of dicts (python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a csv file (uneditable), which looks like this:

```
fruit,price,amount
apple,1,2
banana,3,4
kiwi,5,6
```

that I've read into a list of dicts:

```
goodies = []
with open(blabla) as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for fruit in file:
        goodies.append(fruit)
```

It looks like this:

```
goodies = [{'fruit' : 'apple', 'price' : '1', 'amount':'2'}, {'fruit' : 'banana', 'price' : '3', 'amount':'4'}, {'fruit' : 'kiwi', 'price' : '5', 'amount':'6'}]
```

What I actually need:

```
fruit = [{'apple': [1, 2]}, {'banana': [3, 4]}, {'kiwi': [5, 6]}]
```

The goal is to be able to compare the values with another list of values and receive the fruit it's referring to, kinda like:

```
check = [5, 6]
# compare with all fruit
Output: kiwi
```

I can't tell if I can read the file better or have to fix it somehow afterwards, so any help would be appreciated.

What I have tried:

1. Using goodies to make a new list (don't know why this won't format as code, sorry!)

   fruit = []
   for i in range(len(goodies)):
   f = list(goodies[i].values())
   fruit.append(f)

Resulting in:

```
[['apple', '1', '2'], ['banana', '3', '4'], ['kiwi', '5','6']]
```

2. Taking the above and trying a tuple:

   fruit01 = {tuple(sub[:1]): tuple(sub[1:]) for sub in fruit}

Resulting in (why are those funny commas there?):

```
{('apple',):('1','2'), ('banana',):('3','4'), ('kiwi',):('5','6')}
```

Disclaimer: this is my first encounter with python and first question here, lemme know if I'm doing it wrong :)

Comment: What does your input file look like?

Comment: Just edited that in at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some dictionary creation:

```
goodies = []
with open(blabla) as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for fruit in file:
        goodies.append({fruit['fruit']: [fruit[x] for x in fruit if x != 'fruit']})
```

Comment: Yes!! Almost there! I probably should have mentioned though that I'm getting the csv file as a command line argument and another file could be given to me, which would be almost identical, except with more columns (the top line would look kinda like "fruit,crates,amount,isle,price"), so is there a way to do the same, without hardcoding it? And is there a way to keep the numbers as ints and the words as strings?